# Most Appropriate Component to use in MUI for a Banner Image

Tags: material-ui

I'm trying to add a banner to my React App for the profile page, using MUI since there is no specific "Banner" Component, what would be the most appropriate component to use for a banner in Material UI?

The Youtube Account page banner is kind of what I want, I would like the banner to be mobile-friendly.

```
<div className="Profile">
  //banner here
      <Stack alignItems="center" pt={8}>
      <Avatar
        sx={{
        
          width: 200,
          height: 200,
        }}
        src={dummyurl}
      ></Avatar>

      <username>Test Name</username>
      </Stack>
    </div>
```

The Following tags could be used :

1. Img tag (Vanilla HTML)
2. Paper
3. Avatar

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Please let me know if this is not the right way to ask this type of question

Comment: What constitutes a banner ?

Comment: just an image placed on top of the page

Comment: I don't see the benefit in using any MUI component to achieve this, if it really is just an image.  
Just use CSS/JSS styling directly and use ``object-fit: cover`` on your ``<img/>`` tag.

Comment: appreciate it :)